# How to stop a windows virus run in Wine from infecting executables?

Tags: wine, malware

Yesterday all *.exe files on my machine were infected by Win32.Neshta virus after I ran one program via wine. I cured the machine with `rm -rf ~/.wine`, but it's no good anyway.

So, I decided to set owner root:root and mode 644 on all *.exe, *.com... files. But the owner of the directories is still me. So, I (and, therefore, viruses) can freely rename/remove *.exe files. It's bad.

How can I protect *.exe files from being modified/ renamed/ removed by viruses?

Now I have two ideas:

- `chattr +i`
- make a hardlink for all *.exe to a separate root directory

Comment: You answered your own question: `chattr +i`

Comment: @user14284: How did you discover that you had the virus?  I ask because I use wine apps and this type of info can be  useful.

Comment: Run wine in a chroot jail or remove the emulated access to the rest of your computer (see http://wiki.winehq.org/SecuringWine - `winetricks sandbox`).

Comment: I don't see how hardlinks will help, but `chattr +i` sounds fine.

Answer (score 4):

You should know that [Wine is not a sandbox](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_good_is_Wine_at_sandboxing_Windows_apps.3F). Programs running under Wine are not limited to the Windows API; in theory, a Wine-aware virus could easily detect that it's running under Wine, and switch to using host (e.g. Linux) APIs to do as much damage as a Linux malware could.

The most reliable way of isolation is a full virtual machine. Less complete (but possibly more practical) ways would be to run the program under Wine inside a chroot or a container, however that still leaves the host kernel exposed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Wine, just use a Windows virtual machine using VirtualBox. I have used that method in school and it worked quite well. If the virtual machine gets a virus, simply delete it and make a new one.