# Do I really need an antivirus on Debian 7?

Tags: malware

I use Debian 7 and I visit unknown and different websites. I want to know that people say that we get virus form internet and those virus hack our Bank accounts. Do I really need any antivirus?

I have 512 MB RAM. Also, I do not install software from our sources except repository.

My RAM is 47% used.

I have also installed Wine.

Comment: As far as I know, antivirus software for Linux-based systems does not exist. Does anyone know different?

Comment: @FaheemMitha, [ClamAV](http://clamav.net/) was developed for Unix. (According to the related [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamav).)

Comment: @manatwork Interesting. The name sounds familiar, but I have never looked at this before to my knowledge.

Comment: @Utkarsh Why the answer change?

Comment: @PMInt I dont know that which is the best answer!. I am just playing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An antivirus for Debian really is not a requirement, but if you share files with others, it may be wise to scan the files before sharing them.

An antivirus isn't very needed because Linux is open source, which means that everyone can tell where the flaws are, even if there are many flaws, but nobody has discovered them yet (including attackers), or they are minor (they don't compromise an important part of the system), attackers can't do much.

I have never used an antivirus with Linux and I haven't got a problem. Of course it's safer to do it because you never know, it's up to you.

Comment: answer all my questions and i will choose only YOURS as the best answer!

Comment: I did answered it?

Comment: no no see my profile and answer all questions

Comment: That's not how it works. I asked why the change because it's mostly an opinion based question which means all answers are good, so you should keep the first answer you chose in my opinion. You cannot tell someone 'if you answer all my questions I choose yours', all questions are seperated.

Answer (score 6):

On the Linux and other Unix-like operating systems, the main threats are rootkits. From my experience, the threat of viruses, especially on a distribution like Debian 7 is pretty low (near to nonexistent). However, this doesn't makes you immune from malware implemented in sites that exploit the (mostly javascript) vulnerabilities of the browsers. So please stay away from sites that your browser is resisting to enter because it's a reported attack site.

Wine is a different beast though. From my and some of my friends' experience, some Windows USB removable device viruses can run on Wine. While this doesn't harm you and your computer, you start to spread malware and your computer becomes a carrier. Because of this, you may want to make sure that the drive is clean before exposing it to Wine.

If you're visiting "that dangerous" sites, you can check rootkits with `chkrootkit` and `rkhunter`. To prevent false positives and false negatives, please keep them up to date. If I remember correctly, `rkhunter` scans every month automatically and mails a report to the designated administrator of the computer (this is either `root` user or the first `normal user` account on the Debian, I cannot remember now).

Please remember. On normal and moderately dangerous use-case scenarios, you won't get a virus or persistent malware on a Linux system. This is by design. Hope you enjoy Debian and use it for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

There are reasons against antivirus on Linux and some reasons for it.

#### Reasons against

1. Most people don't write viruses for Linux simply because it isn't as wide spread as Windows and Mac, so that helps right there.[-1-](http://www.netmarketshare.com/operating-system-market-share.aspx?qprid=8&qpcustomd=0)
2. Most Linux virus scanners will only be looking for Windows viruses, making for a much safer way to scan detachable media (jump drives and external Hard Drives). I have yet to find a scanner that specifically looks for Linux viruses.
3. When running a Windows Virus scanner looking for Windows viruses on a Linux machine, there is the possibility that it will find some legitimate Linux process that looks close enough to a Windows virus, remove it, and crash something important.

#### Reasons For

1. There is always a need for some basic security steps [-2-](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity) even beyond a virus scanner.
2. With Wine installed, there is a chance that you can get infected with a Windows virus [-3-](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32742/how-to-stop-a-windows-virus-run-in-wine-from-infecting-executables) though it will suffer the same kinds of issues that most Windows programs experience.
3. Many exploits on the OS are not just *in* the OS. All of the software on your machine is vulnerable and a virus scanner may just pick up something that looks close enough to the Windows version.

I have frequent contact with Windows machines so I occasionally run one just to check the shares and my Wine instance.

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago I helped diagnose/analyze a very crude exploit targeting linux machines and distributed through fake gtk themes.  The themes didn't work, and people just assumed that's all there was to it. No harm done right?  Finding and installing themes doesn't take long anyway...

What the fake theme did is install a script that used a high port to connect to a remote server and after that operate as a node in a coordinated bot net.  The perpetrator made no attempt to cover his/her tracks, and turned out to be using the bot net to run DoS attacks on small gameservers.

Here's some take home points about that:

- If you are downloading and installing software where you are even a little bit uncertain about the source (the distribution point looked very innocent, but wasn't) **do it as an unprivileged user**.  If and when you are really satisfied with the legitimacy of it, you can install it as root.  You don't have to be totally paranoid -- the vast majority of freeware online is what it is.  Just be careful.
- **Use your firewall.** Only allow specific ports for new connections, etc.
  This is hardly foolproof, since a stow-away could pretend to be a web browser, but note that the aforementioned gtk theme thing did not even bother to do this  -- the author just presumed his/her target audience was equally lazy in not configuring a firewall.  The idea here is not, primarily, to prevent unwanted connection requests coming *in* (although that's good to do too), it's to detect/prevent illegitimate requests going *out* from malware that's already resident.
- **Watch your network traffic.** If you have a firewall set up and you are aware of what internet services your system is actually using, there should NOT be much going on when those aren't in use.  Meaning, if you aren't actively clicking links, there should be little to none.  If there is, close some tabs.  If it doesn't stop, restart the browser.  If it still doesn't stop, you need to do some investigating.

The point about firewalls and networking are important because much/most crude malware out there -- and perhaps, most sophisticated malware<sup>1</sup> -- is probably intended (I'm guessing, BTW) for the purpose of creating coordinated zombie bot nets. That's the biggest use value your computer has to your attacker.  Just wrecking stuff is not so useful.  The upside of that is the perpetrator won't want to otherwise expose the scheme, and will want the zombie to remain in good health.  So it won't do anything particularly bad to *your* computer (unless you run a gameserver, lol).

<sup>1</sup> Linux is probably much safer than mainstream OS's WRT to the sophisticated stuff because A) targeting a mainstream OS gives you way more potential targets, B) sophisticated attackers will be aware geeky linux types are probably on average much riskier targets ;)  The gtk theme attack was obviously not very well thought out.